# How to parse Historical BTC Data from Coinmarketcap?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to learn how to web scrape BTC historical data from Coinmarketcap.com using Python, requests, and BeautifulSoup.

I would like to parse the following:

1)Date

2)Close

3)Volume

4)Market Cap

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent': ua.chrome}
response = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/', headers=header)

# html.parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')  

tags = soup.find_all('td')
print(tags)
```

I am able to scrape the data I need but I am not sure how to parse it correctly. I would prefer to have the dates go back as far as possible ('All Time'). Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the ***[link](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20191020)*** you wanna make use of to get data from all time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a function which takes the number of months to return (you could alter this but months is a good enough example) then use pandas read_html to grab the table and subset for columns. This is currently set-up to work from today's date.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_date_range(number_of_months:int):
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_end = now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    dt_start = (now - relativedelta(months=number_of_months)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    return f'start={dt_start}&end={dt_end}'

number_of_months = 3

table = pd.read_html(f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?{get_date_range(number_of_months)}')[0]
table = table[['Date', 'Close**', 'Volume','Market Cap']]
print(table)
```

Comment: Did I do something wrong? I received an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xboss/PycharmProjects/Practice_Makes_Perfect/venv/coinmarketcap.com.py", line 105, in <module>
    table = pd.read_html(f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?{get_date_range(number_of_months)}')[0]
  File "C:/Users/xboss/PycharmProjects/Practice_Makes_Perfect/venv/coinmarketcap.com.py", line 100, in get_date_range
    dt_start = (now - relativedelta(months=n)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: I did a replacement and forgot to put in edit. Please try now.

Comment: This is beautiful work @QHarr. Ty good sir! =) I will study this and will learn a lot from it.

Comment: getting `ValueError: No tables found` error

Comment: See answer below. Looks like page has changed since this was written.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

It seems CoinMarketCap changed their DOM, so here is an update:

```py
import lxml.html
import requests
from typing import Dict, List


def coinmarketcap_get_btc(start_date: str, end_date: str) -> List[Dict]:
    # Build the url
    url = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start={start_date}&end={end_date}'
    # Make the request and parse the tree
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
    # Extract table and raw data
    table = tree.find_class('cmc-table')[0]
    xpath_0, xpath_1 = 'div[3]/div/table/thead/tr', 'div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[%d]/div'
    cols = [_.text_content() for _ in table.xpath(xpath_0 + '/th')]
    dates = (_.text_content() for _ in table.xpath(xpath_1 % 1))
    m = map(lambda d: (float(_.text_content().replace(',', '')) for _ in table.xpath(xpath_1 % d)),
            range(2, 8))
    return [{k: v for k, v in zip(cols, _)} for _ in zip(dates, *m)]
```

Getting a df instead is as simple as using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`.

---

## Original

You can `requests` and `lxml` for this:

Here is a function `coinmarketcap_get_btc` that will take the start and end dates as parameters and gather the relevant data

```
import lxml.html
import pandas
import requests


def float_helper(string):
    try:
        return float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return None


def coinmarketcap_get_btc(start_date: str, end_date: str) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    # Build the url
    url = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start={start_date}&end={end_date}'
    # Make the request and parse the tree
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
    # Extract table and raw data
    table = tree.find_class('table-responsive')[0]
    raw_data = [_.text_content() for _ in table.find_class('text-right')]
    # Process the data
    col_names = ['Date'] + raw_data[:6]
    row_list = []
    for x in raw_data[6:]:
        _, date, _open, _high, _low, _close, _vol, _m_cap, _ = x.replace(',', '').split('\n')
        row_list.append([date, float_helper(_open), float_helper(_high), float_helper(_low),
                         float_helper(_close), float_helper(_vol), float_helper(_m_cap)])
    return pandas.DataFrame(data=row_list, columns=col_names)
```

You can always leave out the columns that are not of interest and add further functionalities (e.g. accepting `datetime.datetime` objects as dates).

**Attention**, the `f-string` used to build the URL requires at least version 3.x of Python (I believe 3.6), so if you are using an old version just use either one of the `'string{var}.format(var=var)'` or `'string%s' % var` notations.

**Example**

```
df = coinmarketcap_get_btc(start_date='20130428', end_date='20191020')
df
#              Date    Open*     High      Low  Close**        Volume    Market Cap
# 0     Oct 19 2019  7973.80  8082.63  7944.78  7988.56  1.379783e+10  1.438082e+11
# 1     Oct 18 2019  8100.93  8138.41  7902.16  7973.21  1.565159e+10  1.435176e+11
# 2     Oct 17 2019  8047.81  8134.83  8000.94  8103.91  1.431305e+10  1.458540e+11
# 3     Oct 16 2019  8204.67  8216.81  7985.09  8047.53  1.607165e+10  1.448240e+11
# 4     Oct 15 2019  8373.46  8410.71  8182.71  8205.37  1.522041e+10  1.476501e+11
# ...           ...      ...      ...      ...      ...           ...           ...
# 2361  May 02 2013   116.38   125.60    92.28   105.21           NaN  1.168517e+09
# 2362  May 01 2013   139.00   139.89   107.72   116.99           NaN  1.298955e+09
# 2363  Apr 30 2013   144.00   146.93   134.05   139.00           NaN  1.542813e+09
# 2364  Apr 29 2013   134.44   147.49   134.00   144.54           NaN  1.603769e+09
# 2365  Apr 28 2013   135.30   135.98   132.10   134.21           NaN  1.488567e+09
# 
# [2366 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you @niko for taking the time to thoroughly explain each step. I will learn a lot thanks to you... and for that I am truly grateful! =)

Comment: This does NOT seem to work anymore ... Maybe coinmarketcap prevented this kind of actions ...

Comment: @CharlyEmpereur-mot They are not really preventing it, but they changed the DOMs. Check the edit for an updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the ways how you can get your aforementioned fields out of that table using `BeautifulSoup` library. I used `.select()` instead of `.find_all()` to locate the desired items.

Working solution:

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start={}&end={}'

def get_coinmarketcap_info(url,s_date,e_date):
    response = requests.get(url.format(s_date,e_date))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

    for items in soup.select("table.table tr.text-right"):
        date = items.select_one("td.text-left").get_text(strip=True)
        close = items.select_one("td[data-format-market-cap]").find_previous_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
        volume = items.select_one("td[data-format-market-cap]").get_text(strip=True)
        marketcap = items.select_one("td[data-format-market-cap]").find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
        yield date,close,volume,marketcap

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataframe = (elem for elem in get_coinmarketcap_info(link,s_date='20130428',e_date='20191020'))
    df = pandas.DataFrame(dataframe)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Ty @SIM for your amazing response! This is so helpful and informative! =) I also really appreciate you showing how to convert the data to a pandas dataframe as well.